In MATLAB, assigning a double-precision calculation result to a sym array or it's elements lead to different resulting data type?
When a sym array is created as a variable in Matlab, assign double-precision calculation result to it, such as to itself or to it's elements, will cause different type of the variable. For example
en=[1.24;1.346;1.441];
eqh=[0.661;0.619;0.568];
eqx=[-0.309;-0.357;-0.392];
eh=[1.594;1.583;1.545];
exqh=sym([]);
exqh=en(1).*eqh(1)+eqx(1).*eh(1);
disp(class(exqh))

the result is double but
exqh2=sym([]);
exqh2(1)=en(1).*eqh(1)+eqx(1).*eh(1);
disp(class(exqh2(1)))

the result is sym.
What is the reason for the different type of the variable?

Because it is the only one using exqh, your other symbolic variable....... Why do you defined as sym and then overwrite them?

@AnderBiguri But exqh is a number.

Okay, I will delete sym. @AnderBiguri

Do you understand why you have sym?

I do not know. Sometime I do not have sym, and matlab tell me wrong, so I add sym.@AnderBiguri

@AnderBiguri Can you teach me when I should add sym and when I should not.

That is the best way of making sure you have a lot of errors and bad code. Try not to make code with lot of errors and bad code! Understand what you are doing or you will never get better. exqh is not a number if you inspect it properly

Yes: Do you want do do numerical mathematics? Do not use sym. Do you need to do symbolic mathematics? Use sym.

@AnderBiguri I am a bit confused about when to use sym. Next time I meet this question, I will ask again.

Your sample code, in addition to being very difficult to read because it's all on one line, has numerous syntax errors. Please correct those so that others are able to reproduce your problem. Also, the second code snippet with exqh2 displays the class for exqh. I assume that is also an error.

@beaker Thanks a lot. I may have corrected those.

@Y.zeng The result of the expression is a double. The first snippet overwrites the variable with both the new value and the new type. The second snippet assigns the double result to a symbolic vector, converting the type to match the vector. This seems to be consistent with all of the variable types, like cell or uint8.

@beaker  There is no double vector, only symbolic vector?

@Y.zeng Clearly there is a double vector. In fact, vectors are doubles by default. A = [1 2 3 4] is a double vector. A = 42 is a double vector with 1 element. A = [] is a double vector with no elements. I mean, this is about as basic as MATLAB gets. Your code, however declares exqh and exqh2 to be symbolic variables. Why you are doing that, I have no idea. You're not evaluating symbolic expressions, so it doesn't seem to make sense.
